# MediaPlayer with setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) not playing android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, ringtone

I am working on an Audio calling app and trying to play `.mp3` file stored in `raw` folder.

I wanted this this file to be played as an `Ringtone`

For this I used `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);`

When I use this stream the `.mp3` is not played (or may be playing I am not able to hear the sound )

If I don't specify any `AudioStreamType` , then the file is played as an `MUSIC` stream , which I don't want

**Note:** Volume of every type (Ringtone,Notification,Call,Music) is set to full in my device

**My code**

```
public MediaPlayer playRingtone(int fileName, boolean loopRingtone) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, fileName);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            AudioAttributes.Builder b = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
            b.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE);
            b.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(b.build());
        } else {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        }
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(loopRingtone);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        return mediaPlayer;
    }
```

Comment: What device are you using? Most devices I have tested are fine but I have had problems with a Note 8 and a Sony.